# Making python aware of packages lacking __init__.py

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I am unable to import `mpl_toolkits` on OS X, apparently because of the lack of an `__init__.py` file in the package directory (`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/mpl_toolkits`).

```
$ python -c 'import mpl_toolkits'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mpl_toolkits

$ ls /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/mpl_toolkits
axes_grid  axes_grid1  axisartist  exceltools.py  exceltools.pyc  gtktools.py  gtktools.pyc  mplot3d
```

The subpackage `mplot3d` does have an `__init.py__` but it cannot be imported either:

```
$ ls /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/
__init__.py  __init__.pyc  art3d.py  art3d.pyc  axes3d.py  axes3d.pyc  axis3d.py  axis3d.pyc  proj3d.py  proj3d.pyc

$ python -c 'from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mpl_toolkits.mplot3d
```

Since OS X 10.11, even root lacks write permissions in `/System`.  I am aware that one can boot into recovery mode and disable System Integrity Protection by executing `csrutil disable`, which would allow creation of the missing `__init.py__` file.  However, is there a simpler way to make python aware of this package?

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're still on Python 2. Matplotlib dropped support for Python 2 a while ago. The Python dev team itself is dropping all Python 2 support in literally a week (start of 2020). You need at least Python 3.6 for the latest Matplotlib to work.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I installed python3.  Do you know if the reason for the module-not-found error is simply the lack of the `__init.py__`?

Comment: @user001: It's supposed to be like that. `mpl_toolkits` is a namespace package, which doesn't need `__init__.py`. That doesn't work on Python 2, though.